# Swig/Python detected a memory leak

Tags: python, swig, maya

I try to learn Maya (3d Software) API with Python, but I encounter some problems..

```
class Foo (node):
    def __init__ (self, arg):
        if isinstance (arg, str):
            fGlobal = OpenMaya.MGlobal()
            fGlobal.selectByName (arg , OpenMaya.MGlobal.kReplaceList)
            selected = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
            fGlobal.getActiveSelectionList(selected);
            obj = OpenMaya.MObject()
            selected.getDependNode(0,obj)
        else :
            obj = arg
```

Everytime i use this class, Maya returns me a warning message.

> swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'MGlobal *', no destructor
>   found.

Does someone know what does it mean ?

Comment: I think it means your class doesn't have a destructor.

Comment: To be more precise it means that whilst you may have had a destructor of some sort available for real SWIG didn't know about it when generating the wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, it seems that the [MGobal](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/api/class_m_global.html) class is static.

Comment: How did you solve this problem?
I get this from Autodesk's own example! :O

Comment: I think you just have to use OpenMaya.MGlobal.selectByName () directly, instead of create an instance and call the method.